# Programmatically disable IE Automatic Configuration Settings (proxy.pac) with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working within a corporate network, my IE connection options use local proxy.pac file.
This proxy.pac stops all
`findElements(By.xpath)`
from finding any elements.
how can i programmatically disable this proxy.pac when running selenium?
i am using `selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar`

Comment: Why are you using an historic version of Selenium?

Comment: its the only one i have available. we cannot download from internet from corporate network :-(

Comment: I would therefore suggest you try to work your way up the management chain until this happens. To give you some perspective, 2.21 is over a year old....a lot will have changed.

Comment: thats not an option i am afraid... i am not management material

Comment: Don't you have the privileges to change IE proxy ?